# android - GCM Send-to-Sync message

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm writing an application that need to read notifications from a "MySql" database... I want send a message from my server to app that when a notification send to a user, it sync notifications with my db...

I read about it on net, and I found something about Google Cloud Message (GCM) that has a service called `"Send-to-Sync Message"` but i can't find a good tutorial... I don't know how to use this thing in my app.

Could you please help me or give me a good tutorial?

Does it need a VPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is GCM documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).There also you can find tutorial about [GCM server implementation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html). Also about "Send-to-Sync Message" pattern you can read this [advanced topic](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html). And you can use for debug purposes my [test push server](http://1-dot-sigma-freedom-752.appspot.com/). Hope, this help you.

Comment: I've downloaded json configuration following the Google tutorial that gives me server api and registration Id. If I use these parameters in your Web server, to send a notification, the server returns failure. Any suggestion?

Comment: First, what the error is coming within the Google's response? You should see something like that  http://clip2net.com/s/3uA52Ey

Comment: So, if you are getting the "InvalidRegistration" error it means you are trying to use invalid registration id ( see https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http) . Make sure that you are using the valid registration id, for experiment, try to replace your registration id with "ABCbla-bla..." and will see what happens, if the error will be the same it definitly means yours registratoin id is invalid. Also, make sure that your client use the same api key which you are putting in the first field of my test server. Please let me know if you will still have the problem.

Comment: I'm using the reg_id/ApiKey that i found in to the page where i download my json configuration. So i can not understand what could be the problem :/ 
if i change the reg_id with another string, the result is the same

Comment: @garsim I don't really understand what the json with the reg_id you are talking about!? As far as I know, the reg_id should be gotten by client side, i.e. by your application. And only when client (app) gets the reg_id then it sends id to your server. So, I'm pretty sure you use the incorrect reg_id. You should take it from client side, when client would get it from GCM service. And when you get reg_id client side, only after that you should put it on my test server. And expected behaviour is your client should get the message from test server.

Comment: json configuration comes from the point 2 of this page https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start and it would contain apikey + senderid.

Comment: Yeah, but senderId != reg_id . The senderId should be used by the client to get reg_id. To use my test server you should put your api_key here http://clip2net.com/s/3uAXCG6. Only when your client gets the  reg_id then you will past that reg_id here http://clip2net.com/s/3uAYBVq and everything should work.

Comment: Ok! Good! Finally, with your apk i found the reg_id (hallelujah!), but now your test server returns an output with this error "MismatchSenderId" O_o

Comment: You get the "MismatchSenderId" because, now, you put incorrect api_key :) If you have taken the reg_id from the sample apk you should keep in mind that I use the different api key. That's why if you take the reg_id from my apk client you shouldn't change the api_key put in the first field by default http://clip2net.com/s/3uB4aE4 . The api_key parameter is bound to sender_id as "one-to-one", you should understand that each client (apk) uses its own sender_id to get the reg_id. Summary: senderId<->api_key (one-to-one) => sender, apikey <-> reg_id (one_to_many).